# Using masks to select subdirectories for transfer with WinSCP

Tags: ftp, wildcard, winscp

I have several directories with varying names `x1`,`x2`,`x3`,etc., each of which contains several subdirectories `a`,`b`,`c`, etc., whose names do not vary between directories `x`.
I'm trying to use WinSCP to download only the files in subdirectory `a` from each, while preserving the directory structure, as shown below.

```
x1/a/files
x2/a/files
x3/a/files
```

I assume it would be simple to do this using the select file mask, for example

```
x*/a/
```

With the option "Apply to directories" selected.

However this selects nothing, and I can find no variation of the selection mask that will achieve what I want.

What is the correct file mask syntax for what I'm trying to do?

---

In case all the above is unclear, the following shell command is an analogue of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
cp -r --parents x*/a/ targetdir
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no really straightforward way to do this with WinSCP as it does not have a feature similar to the `--parents`.

Only way is to explicitly exclude all subdirectories you do not want to transfer:

```
| b/; c/
```

(The `|` denote an exclude mask).

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask